# How to make db structure for multiple input in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my current structure for MySQL database

```
id | item_name  | item_files 
------------------------------------------
1  | Item A     | file1.zip,file2.zip,file3.zip
2  | Item B     | file3.zip
```

Example I create simple form to fill up `Item Name` and `Multiple upload files` then store it to db.

**Question :-**

1. How to design the db structure for accept the multiple files?
2. There have a way which I don't want to use `explode`, `implode` to get the `file1.zip file2.zip file3.zip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalize your data tables

**items table**

```
id  | item_name
--------------
1  | Item A
2  | Item B
```

**item_files table**

```
id  | item_id | item_files  
----------------------------------- 
1  | 1      | file1.zip
2  | 1      | file2.zip
3  | 1      | file3.zip 
4  | 2      | file3.zip
```

Comment: Thanks Mark Baker. Clear now.